# Proper way to pattern match the value of a TypeTree from a ValDef in Scala Macros?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I need to read the fields of a case class and do different things depending on the field's type.

I thought I'd try with a macro, reading the ValDefs and pattern matching on the TypeTree of each, but that doesn't reveal what each TypeTree represents (e.g. Ints and Strings both appear as TypeTrees).

Is there an alternative to calling `typeTree.toString` and matching on the values of the Strings (e.g. "String" or "Int")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TypeTree's `tpe` method to see the underlying type.

Comment: Hmm appears to be null:

Comment: Tried intercepting the ValDef like `first.map(v => println(v.tpt.tpe))` and it appears to be null ([see line 25](https://github.com/julianpeeters/avro-scala-macro-annotations/blob/expansion_order/macros/src/main/scala/avro/scala/macro/annotations/AvroRecordMacro.scala), sorry it's not very minimized). Besides that, won't that get me `Type`, not an `Int` without tpe.toString?

Comment: If it's an annotation macro, then its annottee deliberately doesn't have any types when the macro expands.

Comment: You'll have to do c.typeCheck of something like `{ type T = ${v.tpt}; () }` and then extract the typed result from `type T`.

Comment: Hi again Eugene. This strategy has been working well for me, but now I need to get the `tpe` of `List[Option[String]]` but the typecheck returns `List[Option[...]]`. Is there any way to typecheck the whole tree, perhaps recursively? I tried looking for the type parameters, couldn't find them other than in the raw tree (from which I don't know how to extract a `Type`), and recursively typechecking the `rhs` extracted from `TypeDef(mods, name, tparams, rhs)` led to an error that I can't figure out how to  solve: `The argument types of an anonymous function
must be fully known.`