# Scala macros: Derive type signature from a ValDef

Tags: scala, macros

A very straightforward macro compat backed macro annotation.

```
def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._

    annottees.map(_.tree) match {
      case (classDef @ q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$params) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }")
        :: Nil if mods.hasFlag(Flag.CASE) =>
        val name = tpname.toTermName
        val typeName = tpname.toTypeName
        val res = q"""
         $classDef
         object $name {
           ..${doStuff(c)(typeName, name, params.head)}
         }
         """
        c.Expr[Any](res)

      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid annotation target, this must be a case class")
    }
  }
```

So all very simple straightforward fun. The bit causing problems originates from the `$params` above, which are just `List[List[ValDef]]`, namely somehow the type signature is getting lost.

```
def accessors(c: blackbox.Context)(
    params: Seq[c.universe.ValDef]
  ): Iterable[(c.universe.TermName, c.universe.TypeName)] = {
    import c.universe._

    params.map {
      case ValDef(mods: Modifiers, name: TermName, tpt: Tree, rhs: Tree) => {
        // tpt.tpe = kaboom, null pointer
        name -> TypeName(tpt.tpe.typeSymbol.fullName)
      }
    }
  }
```

The `tpe` on `ValDef` comes back as `null`, so the defs are not typed, but I need the type signature of the params to achieve what I want. How can I get at the type signature of the params without it blowing up?

Ironically, `showCode(tpt)` does produce the right type string, so this can be worked around with `TypeName(tpt.toString)`, but I'm not sure why `tpe` is not accessible.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the answer and comments of Eugene Burmako in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671379/proper-way-to-pattern-match-the-value-of-a-typetree-from-a-valdef-in-scala-macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to evaluate the type arguments using `c.typepcheck` in `c.TypeMode` as follows:

```
  /**
    * Retrieves the accessor fields on a case class and returns an iterable of tuples of the form Name -> Type.
    * For every single field in a case class, a reference to the string name and string type of the field are returned.
    *
    * Example:
    *
    * {{{
    *   case class Test(id: UUID, name: String, age: Int)
    *
    *   accessors(Test) = Iterable("id" -> "UUID", "name" -> "String", age: "Int")
    * }}}
    *
    * @param params The list of params retrieved from the case class.
    * @return An iterable of tuples where each tuple encodes the string name and string type of a field.
    */
  def accessors(
    params: Seq[ValDef]
  ): Iterable[Accessor] = {
    params.map {
      case ValDef(_, name: TermName, tpt: Tree, _) => {
        Accessor(
          name,
          c.typecheck(tq"$tpt", c.TYPEmode).tpe
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

In this case `Accessor` is a custom `case class` that has to be defined inside a scope where `import c.universe._` is available:

```
  case class Accessor(
    name: TermName,
    paramType: Type
  ) {
    def typeName: TypeName = symbol.name.toTypeName

    def symbol = paramType.typeSymbol
  }
```